# How to add a background image in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to add a background image as a step to creating a basic game but it seems that I can't find a way. The image I am trying to import is the same size as the screen and it's a bmp image.

I also have in my settings folder this line of code which I am sure but not 100% needs to be removed (`self.bg_color = (230, 230,230)`) if I want to blit the image in background.

```
import sys
import pygame
from altarboy import Altarboy
from Ship import Ship
from bullet import bullet
from bullet1 import bullet1
from settings import Settings


class SpiritualWar:

    def __init__(self):    
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("SpiritualWar")
        self.Ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.bullet1s = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.altarboys = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self._create_fleet()
…
…
    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.Ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        for bullet1 in self.bullet1s.sprites():
            bullet1.draw_bullet1()
        self.altarboys.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 3):

Possible duplicate of [How to add a background image in python-pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485518/how-to-add-a-background-image-in-python-pygame). I also recommend you to see [Pygame: Adding a background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923023/pygame-adding-a-background). Next time, spend some minutes searching your question in StackOverflow before asking it. This way there will be less posts and SO will be cleaner, which helps to find solutions with ease.

I could not test the solution myself, but you can try adding the next line to the funciton `__init__()`:

```py
self.bg_image = pygame.image.load("player1.png")
```

And then changing your first line in function `_update_screen()`:

```py
self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
```

for:

```py
self.screen.blit(self.bg_image, (0, 0))
```